# cannot delete a record

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

```
<%@page import="java.util.logging.Logger"%>
<%@page import="java.util.logging.Level"%>
<%@page language="java" import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page language="java" import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
     //String id4 = request.getParameter("id3");
     //int id5=Integer.ParseInt("id4");
    String id4 = request.getParameter("id3");

    if (id4 != null) {
        // int  id4 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id3.trim()"));
        Connection con = null;
        int id5 = Integer.parseInt("id4");

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/login?       user=root&password=root");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String sql = "delete from login2 where id=" + id5;
            int i = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            if (i > 0) {
                response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
            }
            out.println("failed");
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
%>
```

I am not able to delete a record..the id4 is taking null value.how to fix it..

```
String id = request.getParameter("id");
int id1 = Integer.parseInt(id);
final String email = request.getParameter("email");
final String password = request.getParameter("pass");
Connection con = null;

try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/login? user=root&password=root");

    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String idd = (String) session.getAttribute("id1");
    String sql = "INSERT INTO login2(email,pass)" + " VALUES('" + email + "','" + password + "')";
    stmt.execute(sql);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.println("successfully registered");
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from login2");
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    out.println("<html><body>");
    out.println("<table border=1 width=50% height=50%>");
    out.println("<tr><th>id</th><th>email</th><th>pasword</th>   <th>action</th><tr>");

    while (rs.next()) {
        int id2 = rs.getInt("id");
        String id9 = request.getParameter("id");
        int id0 = Integer.parseInt(id9);
        String email1 = rs.getString("email");
        String pass1 = rs.getString("pass");
        //int s = rs.getInt("sal"); 
        out.println("<tr>  <td>" + id2 + "</td> <td>" + email1 + "</td><td>" + pass1 + "</td>   </tr>");
        out.println("<tr><td><a href=  delete.jsp? id3=<%=rs.getInt(\"id\")%   >delete</a></td></tr>");
        //out.println("<tr><td><a HREF=\"delete.jsp\">link</a></td></tr>");
    }

    out.println("</table>");
    out.println("</html></body>");
}
```

this is my servlet page for displaying the records.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Your delete record jsp must be throwing `NumberFormatException` since your are trying to convert invalid string to number

`int id5 = Integer.parseInt("id4");`  remove `"` around id4 only then id4 string will be converted to int.

if you are getting `null` value of `id4`  in expression `String id4 = request.getParameter("id3");`

**Update:**

Try this : `out.println("<tr><td><a href= \"delete.jsp?id3=\""+ rs.getInt("id") +"\">delete</a></td></tr>");`

in place of `out.println("<tr><td><a href=  delete.jsp? id3=<%=rs.getInt(\"id\")%   >delete</a></td></tr>");`

Comment: Can you please update your question with updated code?

Comment: out.println("<td id='update'><a href='del.jsp?sid='foo'>delete</a>");

Comment: i got the answer..could you tell me how to edit a table  and also adding a new row